# Postback in report viewer using MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, postback, reportviewer

I am using Report Viewer control with the MVC3. When I create a report say Report2.rdlc , and there are 150 records , the pagination of the Report viewer is done. When I click on the page 2 button, a postback function is called , which throws an error as i am using MVC3. Is there any workaround to achieve the records in the page 2 to be displayed.

Or is it possible to display all the records in one page itself? I tried
1) Increasing the height of the Report VIewer and the Report.
2) Setting the ShowPageNavigation to false.

Please Help.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have the ReportViewer control inside an MVC view? I have only seen a basic implementation work with hacks/workarounds, often advanced functionality is broken as ReportViewer relies on things from WebForms that aren't available in MVC.

You best approach would be to use an iframe and a WebForm page to get the full functionality or have you tried turning on/off async rendering?

Comment: Thanks Phil. I am now using the Report viewer in th aspx page and got the report to display the records in the same page itself using the interactive height option.